# How to Make a good if Statement for Tier

Tags: c#

[The error part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyHyI.png) [image: The application i got to make and to run it by tier using if statements]

THE HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT GIVEN   Tiered baseball player salaries. Create a program that will calculate the salary a player will earn based on the following business rules.  Be sure to refer to the general programming guidelines listed above.  Name your project:  TieredPlayerSalaryViaIF - Your Name

Tier 1: For 1 through 49 hits in a season, the player earns $17,500 per hit for ALL hits. 
Tier 2: For 50 through 99 hits, the player earns $20,000 per hit for ALL hits. 
Tier 3: For 100 through 149 hits, the player earns $22,500 per hit for ALL hits. 
Tier 4: For 150 or more hits, the player earns $25,000 per hit for ALL hits. 
Then consider All Star and MVP (most valuable player)  awards:

- If a player is neither an All Star NOR a MVP designation, then add 0% to the tiered salary you calculated above
- If a player is both an All Star AND and a MVP, then add 25% to the tiered salary you calculated above
- If a player is only one of All Star OR a MVP, then add 20% to the tiered salary you calculated above 
  Note that this is a 'simple' calculation - in that once a player reaches the threshold for the next $ level per hit, the player earns that rate for ALL hits they had.  For example, if Player1 had 149 hits in a season, he will earn                                 149  *  22,500  =  $3,352,500.  However, if that Player1 would have produced one more hit (150), he would have earned  150  *  25,000  =  $3,750,000.  Then, consider the impact of the All Star and MVP attributes on the salary calculation mentioned above.

INPUT:  Have the user enter the player’s name, number of hits, one checkbox to indicate if they are an All Star and a second checkbox to indicate if they are a MVP. Then use a Calculate button to process the data.  Process the data only if the user enters a player’s name (any non-space characters typed in constitutes entering a name).  Process the data only if the user entered a valid hit count.  A valid hit count is an integer that is greater than zero, but is less than or equal to 300.  Validate the hit count programmatically – do not use a masked textbox. Use a validation method we covered other than try..catch to perform the validation.  Add a Clear button to clear the data entry fields, checkboxes and calculations.

PROCESSING/OUTPUT: Calculate the player’s earnings based on the Tier they achieved, and display the calculated salary and Tier number. Use an if () … decision structure to determine the Tier number and $ per hit amount (do not use a switch (..case…) decision structure).  Determine any additional salary amount based on All Star/MVP checkbox settings. 
In addition to allowing the entry of the current player name, hits details and calculating the current player’s salary based on the above, also display a separate summary set of information on the window showing the leading player’s name ,  number of hits, salary and Tier number for the player who has had the most hits of all players processed so far, since the Window was opened or since the Clear button was last clicked.  You only need to keep track of the ONE leading player, not all players entered in.   If there are one or more ties, the first player entered who had the most hits will be the leader.

```
this is the code i have but the if statements give errors
```

is supposed to be tiered baseball player salary based on theere number of hits and the player name to be leader and show the player salary

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TieredPlayerSalaryViaIF___Ionut_Cozma
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string Playername;
        int Hits = 0;

        Boolean MVP = false;
        Boolean AllStart = false;

        int Tier = 0;
        int HitSalarymulti = 0;


        double bonuspercentage = 1;
        double ActualSalary = 0;

        string LeaderName;
        int LeaderHits = 0;
        double LeaderSalary;
        int LeaderTier;
        private void Calcbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Playername = nameTextbox.Text;

            Hits = int.Parse(HitsTextbox.Text);


            if (Mvpcheckbox.Checked)
            {
                MVP = true;

            }


            if (AllStartcheckbox.Checked)
            {
                AllStart = true;

            }
// this part wont run even tough i think i put the hits and the greater than and less then in the right context ??

            and the if statement if its in the right context

                        if (Hits <= 49 + Hits  => 1)
                        {

                               Tier = 1;
                         Salarymulti = 17,500;
                        }

                        else if (Hits >= 50 + Hits <= 99)
                        {
                            Tier = 2;
                            Salarymulti = 20,000;
                        }

                        else if (Hits <= 100 + Hits => 149 )
                        {
                            Tier = 3;
                            Salarymulti = 22,500;
                        }

                        else if (Hits <= 150 Hits )
                        {
                           Tier = 4;
                            Salarymulti = 25,000
                        }

                       else  (Hits <= 150 + Hits => )

                        else MessageBox.Show("insert hits entry");

                           return;


                        if (MVP || AllStart)
                        bonuspercentage = 1.2;
                        {
                            bonuspercentage = 1.25;
                        }


                        ActualSalary = Hits * Salarymulti;
                        bonuspercentage


                            Salarylbl.Text = ActualSalary.Tostring("C");
                              Tierlbl.Text = Tier.ToString("C");

                        if (Hits >LeaderHits)
                        {
                            Leadernamelbl.Text = Playername;
                            Leaderhitslbl.Text = Hits.ToString();
                            leadersalarylbl.Text = ActualSalary.ToString();
                                 LeaderTier.Text = Tier.ToString();

                        }

                        Playername = PlayerNameUsvText.Text;

                        if (PlayerName is null 0 Whitesapce)

                         {
                MessageBox.Show(" Error message improper name");
                            return;
                        }
// need help with this part if i wrote it right 
                        switch (Tier)
                        { 

                        case 1:
                            Salarymulti = 17,500;
                        case 2:
                            Salarymulti = 20,000;
                        case: 3
                            Salarymulti = 22,500;
                        default 4:
                            Salarymulti = 25,000;

                        }


// the code wont run right because the case and the if statements dont seem to be made correct i tried research online but i cant really find close code to mine 





            }
        private void clrbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
[the error part of the code ][2]
```

[The code that has errros;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba9de.png)

Comment: i went to tutors but i stil lhave issues with the if staments going in to errors

Comment: consider reducing your description.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: AND STOP YELLING AT US

Comment: to reduce it it might not help explain why its going on in the assigment im new at code and idk how to explain the code in good coding wording about the code not running right

Comment: Your `if` conditions are wrong and they will not compile. You need to change this `if(Hits <= 49 + Hits  => 1){

         }`  to this: `if(Hits <= 49 && Hits  >= 1){

         }`

Comment: thank you so much i will try that really appreciate i suck at describing how to help others understand what i am asking for in coding wording since im new to  this stuff   http://stackoverflow.com/users/4228458/codingyoshi    -                     -CodingYoshi3

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure where you are in your learning. This is a great time for you to understand the value of Object Oriented Programming. Your form no matter how good it looks has nothing to do with the object you're working with or the logic of how one property should interact with another. In this case a BaseBall Player. You would do yourself a lot of favors to create an object similar to the following:

```
public class BallPlayer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfHits { get; set; }

    public bool IsMvp { get; set; }

    public bool IsAllStar { get; set; }

    public double SalaryPerHit
    {
        get
        {
            var salary = 10.0;
            if( NumberOfHits < 150 )
                salary = 15;
            else if( NumberOfHits < 200 )
                salary = 20;
            else if( NumberofHits < 250 )
                salary = 25;

            return salary;
        }
    }

    public double BonusMultiplier
    {
        get
        {
            var multiplier = 1.0;

            if( IsMvp ) multiplier = 1.1;
            else if( IsAllStar ) multiplier = 1.2;

            return multiplier;
        }
    }

    public double CalculateSalary() =>
        SalaryPerHit * BonusMultiplier * NumberOfHits;
}
```

In your form you would create an instance of the `BallPlayer` and your controls when changed would then update the associated property of the `BallPlayer`. Please note there are some values that have been intentionally changed as this is meant to help you get a better understanding of how to improve your code.